# My counter stop when i switch tab (reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to javascript, and I made a counter. It works, however when the tab is inactive it stops and then resumes when I return to the page.
Here is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

function TimeTracker(props){

    const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
    const [timerOn, setTimerOn] = useState(false);

useEffect(()=>{

        let interval = null;

        if(timerOn){
            interval = setInterval(()=>{
                setTime(prevTime => prevTime +10)
            }, 10)

        }else{
            clearInterval(interval)

        }

        return ()=> clearInterval(interval)

    },[timerOn])
    
    return(
    <div>
    
     <p>{("0" + Math.floor((time / 60000) % 60)).slice(-2)} mn</p>
     <p>{("0" + Math.floor((time / 1000) % 60)).slice(-2)} s</p>
     <button onClick={()=>setTimerOn(true)}>Start</button>
     <button onClick={()=>setTimerOn(false)}>Stop</button>


    
    </div>
    
    
    )
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: Check your code before posting it, this snippet is useless since it got an error (and not the declared one in your post)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i am new on this website!

Comment: This might not answer the question but I recommend watching [this presentation about counters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCi6AZMkxcU). It shows the different browser quirks and issues with `setInterval`, and how to fix them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your counter was not efficient**

*If you add a console.log before setTime and start the counter you will notice the extra renders*

**The code below will solve your issue:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

function TimeTracker(props){

const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
const [timerOn, setTimerOn] = useState(false);

useEffect(()=>{

  let interval = null;
  if(timerOn){
      interval = setInterval(()=>{
          setTime(prevTime => prevTime +1)
      }, 1000)

  }else{
      clearInterval(interval)

  }

  return ()=> clearInterval(interval)

},[timerOn])

return(
<div>

 <p>0{Math.floor(time / 60)} mn</p>
 <p>{Math.floor(time % 60)} s</p>
 <button onClick={()=>setTimerOn(true)}>Start</button>
 <button onClick={()=>setTimerOn(false)}>Stop</button>



</div>


)
}
```

Comment: -1 The OP's question was how to run timer even when browser is inactive, but your answer addresses on how to simply the timer inside useEffect

Answer (score 2):

> On most browsers inactive tabs have low priority execution and this can affect JavaScript timers.

Thus, when you not focus on your tab, interval will not work. Its not React problem.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome) question, I wish it help you.

Comment: Hello, thank you! I will check it!